# Difference between Google's Query and Place Autocomplete?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Whats the difference between these two services: Google Place Autocomplete https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete and Google Query autocomplete https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/query
Except theirs descriptions, which are not clear enough.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference between these web services is the following:

- The Place autocomplete service will return as suggestions only places from Google database. These place predictions have a place ID, so you can resolve them to position on the map.
- The Query autocomplete service will return as suggestions both places from Google database and geographic query predictions. The geographic query predictions are not places entities, they don't have place ID, they are search texts like "pizza near Sydney, New South Wales, Australia" that you probably need to pass further to search engine of your app.